# Trying to understand "let" in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, fibonacci, let

I'm trying to expand a simple fibonacci function, and I need to use the values for each term more than once.  So, I figured I'd use `let` to hold onto the values.  But, I'm not getting what I think I should out of the function.

Here is the original `fib` function:

```
(define (fib n)
  (if (< n 2)
      n
      (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

Here is my attempt at doing the same thing, but with `let`:

```
(define (fib-with-let n)
  (if (< n 2)
      0
      (let ((f1 (fib-with-let (- n 1)))
            (f2 (fib-with-let (- n 2))))
        (+ f1 f2))))
```

Results:

```
> (fib 10)
55
> (fib-with-let 10)
0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
(if (< n 2)
    0
    ...)
```

You mean `n`.

Answer (score 6):

You mistyped your base case. In the first version you had:

```
(if (< n 2)
      n
```

But then in your latter version you wrote:

```
(if (< n 2)
      0
```

So just change `0` to `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Your let is not really doing anything. You are still doing all of the extra calculations. Just because you define `f1` as `(fib-with-let (- n 1))` doesn't mean you won't compute the fib of n-1 again. `f2` does **not** use `f1`. If you wanted `f2` to *see* `f1` you would use `let*`. However, even this is not really what you want.

As evidence of this, here are the running times `for fib(35)` and `fib-with-let(35)`:

```
(time (fib 35))
cpu time: 6824 real time: 6880 gc time: 0
(time (fib-with-let 35))
cpu time: 6779 real time: 6862 gc time: 0
```

What you really want to do to avoid extra computations is use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Dynamic_programming_in_computer_programming) and recurse in a [bottom-up fashion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design#Bottom-up_approach).

What you want is the following code:

```
(define (dynprog-fib n)
  (if (< n 2)
      n
      (dynprog-fib-helper 1 1 2 n)))

(define (dynprog-fib-helper n1 n2 current target)
  (if (= current target)
      n2
      (dynprog-fib-helper n2 (+ n1 n2) (add1 current) target)))

(time (dynprog-fib 35))
cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
(time (dynprog-fib 150000))
cpu time: 2336 real time: 2471 gc time: 644
```

As you can see, you can do the first 150,000 fibs in a third of the time the naive approach takes.

---

Since it looks like you are confused about what let does let me illustrate better:

When you say:

```
(let ((a 1)
      (b 2))
  (+ a b))
```

What you are saying is, let a be 1, and b be 2, add them together.
If you instead said:

```
(let ((a 1)
      (b (+ a 1))
  (+ a b))
```

Can you guess what you'd get? Not 3. It would be blow up with `expand: unbound identifier in module in: a`

In simple `let`, your assignments cannot *see* each other.
If you wanted to write the above you would have to use `let*`:

```
(let* ((a 1)
      (b (+ a 1))
  (+ a b))
```

That would give you the 3 you expect. `let*` essentially expands to:

```
(let ((a 1))
     (let ((b (+ a 1)))
          (+ a b)))
```

---

What you thought you were doing with the lets is called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). It's a technique where you store intermediate values so you don't have to repeat them. Let, however, does not do that for you.

Comment: Fantastic answer, I like how thorough you were.

Answer (score 0):

Although your problem is a typo in your `fib-with-let` function, in its simplest form, `let` is "syntatic-sugar" for an anonymous lambda followed by the arguments that are then evaluated and passed to the lamba, which is then evaluated and a final value returned.  So

```
(let ((f1 (fib-with-let (- n 1)))
      (f2 (fib-with-let (- n 2))))
        (+ f1 f2))
```

would be re-written without `let` to look like

```
((lambda (f1 f2) (+ f1 f2))(fib-with-let (- n 1))(fib-with-let (- n 2)))
```